# c# wpf) how to open calendar of Datepicker to upside intentionally?

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker, calendar

What I want to know is very simple. If I click the DatePicker, the calendar is opened downside and cover other things not to be seen.

I tried to search on Properties and internet, stackoverflow but failed to find a solution. Is there a simple, easy solution to solve this?

I always highly appreciate excellent people of stackoverflow.
Thank you so much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to adjust the control template of the DatePicker control to accomplish this.

First get a copy of the original control template. You'll start from the original template and only edit the things you want to change. The easiest way to do this is with Blend.

- Open your project in Blend
- Right click the DatePicker control
- Click Edit Template, then Edit a copy
- Create a new resource dictionary (new... at the bottom) and check the radio button to save the template in it.

Now open the new file you have just created and edit the template as follows. Change this:

```
<Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="True" Placement="Bottom" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=PART_TextBox}" StaysOpen="False"/>
```

To this:

```
<Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="True" Placement="Top" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=PART_TextBox}" StaysOpen="False"/>
```

Give the template a good name:

```
x:key="MyCustomDatePicker"
```

Then update your DatePicker as follows:

```
<DatePicker
    ...
    Template="{StaticResource MyCustomDatePicker}"
    ... />
```

Comment: At first glance, it looked difficult for me because my major is just biochemistry and even haven't used Blend until this time. However, I carefully tried Blend(followed you) and your solution works excellently. My deepest appreciation for you ! Thank you so much !